# Display text given a counters current count

Tags: javascript

At present I have a very basic Javascript counter-style function:

```
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var clicks = 0;
    function onClick() {
        clicks += 1;
        document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
    };
    </script>
    <button type="button" onClick="onClick()">Add One To Chain</button>
    <p>Chain: <a id="clicks">0</a></p>

</body>
```

However now I wish to present the user with different text prompts at different points whilst counting.

For example if the counter reaches 10 I would like it to say hello, and if it reaches 20 it would say something like keep going, and at 30 STOP! and so on.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You need to show an attempt at implementing the desired behaviour. We're here to help, not write code for you. It should be pretty simple with a `switch()` or a bunch of `if()` statements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a switch statement like so:

```
switch (clicks) {
    case 10:
        text = 'Hello';
        break;
    case 20:
        text = 'Keep going';
        break;
    case 30:
        text = 'STOP';
        break;
    default:
        text = clicks;
        break;
}
document.getElementById("clicks").textContent = text;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a dynamic approach. It will alert as many prompts as you fill in the `prompts` array.

```
var clicks = 0,
    prompts = ['Hello', 'Keep going', 'STOP'];

function onClick()
{
    clicks += 1;

    var promptKey = clicks / 10 - 1;

    if (clicks % 10 == 0 && prompts[promptKey] !== undefined) {
        alert(prompts[promptKey]);
    }

    document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use if else in `Javascript` for this to work.

**Here is working example.**

```js
var clicks = 0;

function onClick1() {

  clicks += 1;

  if (clicks == 10) {
    alert("Hello");
  } else if (clicks == 20) {
    document.getElementById("clicks").style.color = "green";
    document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks + " Keep Going";
  } else if (clicks == 30) {
    document.getElementById("clicks").style.color = "red";
    document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks + "Stop !!";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
  }
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onClick="onClick1()">Add One To Chain</button>
<p>Chain: <a id="clicks">0</a>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do it would be like this. I've included comments to help you understand what's up.

```
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var clicks = 0;
    function onClick() {
      clicks += 1;
      var nextClick = clicks + 1; // Get the next click too.
      document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;

      // Based on what the next click will be,
      switch (nextClick) {
        case 10:
          // Put a message in div#message.
          document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = 'hello';
          break;

        case 30:
          document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = 'STAHP';
          break;
      }
    };
  </script>
  <button type="button" onClick="onClick()">Add One To Chain</button>
  <p>Chain: <a id="clicks">0</a></p>

  <!-- A container for the message from JS -->
  <div id="message"></div>
</body>
```

Hope that's helpful!

Answer (score 0):

[Edited]:
The following will be more maintable : Steps and messages are stored in an object rather than hardcoded in a switch case loop.

```
var clicks = 0;
var messages = {"10": "hello", "20": "keep going", "30": "stop"};
function onClick() {
  clicks++;
  document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = (messages.hasOwnProperty(clicks.toString())) ? messages[clicks.toString()] : clicks;
  return;      
};
```

see the following [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d7tqvwyp/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```js
let clicks = 0;
const clickEl = document.getElementById("clicks");

const messages = {
  10: {
    alrt: "Hello"
  },
  20: {
    cls: "keep-going",
    msg: "Keep Going"
  },
  30: {
    cls: "stop",
    msg: "Stop !!"
  }
};

document.getElementById("add-one").addEventListener("click", e => {
  clicks++;
  // default message in output
  let message = clicks;
  // clear className (text color)
  clickEl.className = "";
  // check if there is an object describing what to do for this value
  // key value could be adjusted to accommodate ranges, for example 10-19
  // using %
  if (typeof messages[clicks] !== "undefined") {
    const msgObj = messages[clicks];
    // if there is alert text
    if (typeof msgObj.alrt !== "undefined") {
      alert(msgObj.alrt);
    }
    // override CSS class if available
    if (typeof msgObj.cls !== "undefined") {
      clickEl.className = msgObj.cls;
    }
    // update message if appropriate
    if (typeof msgObj.msg !== "undefined") {
      message += " " + msgObj.msg;
    }
  }
  // display message
  clickEl.textContent = message;
});
```

```css
.keep-going {
  color: green;
}

.stop {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="add-one">Add One To Chain</button>
<p>Chain: <output id="clicks">0</output></p>
```